# Tkinter window not showing in Pycharm

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

I can't get tkinter to work in Pycharm. There is no error message, but the window doesn't pop up. It works perfectly fine in IDLE. Even just a simple window doesn't work:

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
window.mainloop()
```

The output looks like:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I'm on mac os x with python 3.8 and pycharm 2020.1.2.
Some sources suggested installing the package future, but this doesn't work either.

Comment: It sounds stupid but are you sure you are running the good script ? I t happens frequently to me: i am editing one but I keep running the script I was working with before

Comment: Thanks, it actually worked. I had the wrong configuration.